# MySQL query broken

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Ok its late and I am not catching why this is broken. So here goes.. the error is as follows

> syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING
>   or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

typically I would assume its a mising ; ' " or similar, I've checked I have found nothing missing from the surrounding code.

Now despite the possible "injection" factors which I don't care about currently someone please tell me whats wrong with this one line.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO files_posted (ID, when, email, randomkey, count, fileID) VALUES (NULL, $when, $email, $fakeHash, '0', mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fileID']))") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: you should echo your variables on failure in order to test

Comment: Syntactically that line is correct (at least for PHP, wait until you see what `mysql_error` will tell you), so the error must be somewhere else (we need more code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides using a quoted subscript on an embedded (interpolated) variable, you are likely missing some quotes (around values) in the query.

Try this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO files_posted (ID, when, email, randomkey, count, fileID) VALUES (NULL, '".mysql_real_escape_string($when)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($fakeHash)."', '0', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fileID'])."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

If the `$_POST['fileID']` is always expected to be an integer, then it does not need to be wrapped in a `mysql_real_escape_string` call and it would actually be safer (against SQL injection) and possibly more efficient to just cast it to an int:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO files_posted (ID, when, email, randomkey, count, fileID) VALUES (NULL, '".mysql_real_escape_string($when)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($fakeHash)."', '0', ".((int)$_POST['fileID']).')') or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thats what it was, I just didnt enclose everything properly. Like I said its late, and its been a long day. Getting burned out but have that deadline to meet and that sleep to stupidity ratio is kicking in.

Answer (score 1):

One of your variables contains an apostrophe:
$when, $email, $fakeHash

That's my guess. You should use mysql_real_escape_string() for all of those.

Comment: Also, he doesn't need to encapsulate the digit in apostrophes, if it's verified to be an `int` that is.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you enclose all text field values in (single or double) quotes (and make sure they are escaped). The quotes are required to make sure MySQL treats the text as strings and not as something else.

Alternatively, use PDO, and you don't have to worry about that.